# Mysql query not returning expected result on mysql 5.6.10 and 5.6.46?

Tags: mysql, database

When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT
  node_field_data.title,
  node_field_data.type,
  node_field_data.status,
  node_field_data.nid,
  node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created 
FROM
  node_field_data 
  LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        taxonomy_term_field_data.*,
        taxonomy_index.nid 
      FROM
        taxonomy_term_field_data 
        LEFT JOIN
          taxonomy_index 
          ON taxonomy_index.tid = taxonomy_term_field_data.tid 
      WHERE
        taxonomy_term_field_data.vid IN 
        (
          'blog_post_tags'
        )
    )
    taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data 
    ON node_field_data.nid = taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.nid 
WHERE
  (
(taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name = 'lung cancer')
  )
  AND 
  (
(node_field_data.status = '1')
  )
  LIMIT 1;
```

I get The following result:

```
+------------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------------------------+
| title                                    | type      | status | nid   | node_field_data_created |
+------------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------------------------+
| xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx| blog_post |      1 | 14339 |              1332187581 |
+------------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-------+-------------------------+
```

Then I add a where clause `AND (node_field_data.type IN ('blog_post')` in the following manner

```
SELECT
  node_field_data.title,
  node_field_data.type,
  node_field_data.status,
  node_field_data.nid,
  node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created 
FROM
  node_field_data 
  LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        taxonomy_term_field_data.*,
        taxonomy_index.nid 
      FROM
        taxonomy_term_field_data 
        LEFT JOIN
          taxonomy_index 
          ON taxonomy_index.tid = taxonomy_term_field_data.tid 
      WHERE
        taxonomy_term_field_data.vid IN 
        (
          'blog_post_tags'
        )
    )
    taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data 
    ON node_field_data.nid = taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.nid 
WHERE
  (
(taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name = 'lung cancer')
  )
  AND 
  (
(node_field_data.status = '1') 
    AND node_field_data.type = 'blog_post'
  )
;
```

and I get no result (`empty set (0.001 sec)` where it's   from the previous query the type `blog_post` exists.

It's worth noting that using the same db data on a different mysql server version `5.6.43` work. The issue is occurring on mysql version `5.6.10`

Comment: What is the data type of `node_field_data.type`? If it is a CHAR/VARCHAR?TEXT; it is time to start looking for non-printing characters. Add `LEN(node_field_data.type)` to the first query you presented, and if it isn't 9, then that is likely the problem. If it is enum... well, enum is just weird. _Though the fact the MySQL version makes a difference makes me think it is not a non-printing character issue unless the data was recorded/restored slightly differently._

Comment: Thanks, this was good guess but it's varchar(32)  and length returned 9

Comment: Maybe check the tables for errors? If the field is indexed and the index is somehow out of date or corrupt, it could cause similar issues.